# Can you choose who you disguise as when disguising as a class with more than 2 players?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

In TF2, when I'm trying to sneak up on an enemy's sentry nest, my favorite thing to do is disguise myself as a friendly engineer, so that they expect me to help them fix the place up, before breaking out the sappers and stabbers.

This doesn't go over so well when I show up as the engineer guarding the nest.

Assuming I know which engineer it is though, is there a way for me to change which name I use in my disguise, so that I can approach him without danger?

Comment: "sappers and stabbers". Solid gold!

Comment: @Dycker Nah, solid gold would be if I went in with a Saxxy.

Comment: If you have the dead ringer, and you are in a small game, disguise as one of your own team and hold the dead ringer. When they kill you, run away before removing cloak, because the sound is loud. This is good because they think they killed you but in fact, you are just a spy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, no, there is no direct way using the disguise kit to choose who you disguise as; only the team and class. You should, however, be able to re-disguise yourself a few times until the name that pops up is the specific person you want.

The other option for disguising as a specific person is the [Your Eternal Reward](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Your_Eternal_Reward), which always disguises you as the person you backstab, at a cost of losing the normal disguise kit.

Comment: For anyone reading this years later: You CAN disguise while using the YER (it's been changed since this answer was posted).